# How to convert facebook shared youtube link to actual youtube link using C#?

Tags: c#, facebook, url, youtube

I'm trying to convert Youtube link on Facebook to it's original Youtube link.

But I could not find any code similar to this purpose.

I'm getting video url in this format, when posted on facebook

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=137180674769618&id=744284273020098&refid=18&_ft_=qid.6890741645663138454%3Amf_story_key.778345062947352%3Agroup_id.744284273020098%3Atop_level_post_id.778345062947352%3Atl_objid.778345062947352%3Acontent_owner_id_new.100054330590900%3Apage_id.744284273020098%3Asrc.22%3Astory_location.6%3Astory_attachment_style.share%3Afilter.GroupStoriesByActivityEntQuery%3Atds_flgs.3%3Aott.AX89EZnntOWyt_cV%3Apage_insights.%7B%22744284273020098%22%3A%7B%22page_id%22%3A744284273020098%2C%22page_id_type%22%3A%22group%22%2C%22actor_id%22%3A100054330590900%2C%22dm%22%3A%7B%22isShare%22%3A1%2C%22originalPostOwnerID%22%3A0%7D%2C%22psn%22%3A%22EntGroupMallPostCreationStory%22%2C%22post_context%22%3A%7B%22object_fbtype%22%3A657%2C%22publish_time%22%3A1602049213%2C%22story_name%22%3A%22EntGroupMallPostCreationStory%22%2C%22story_fbid%22%3A%5B778345062947352%5D%7D%2C%22role%22%3A1%2C%22sl%22%3A6%7D%7D&__tn__=C-R
```

What I need to find, is the originally posted YouTube link like following..

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxx
```

Where should I start to achieve this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That can't be the link because that is not a valid link.

Comment: Are you sure the above link is accurate? I tried but it is not what I am getting. Or please explain more on how you'd obtain that link.